# Хеширование SHA1

Tags: c#, криптография, хеширование, sha1, password-hash

В сети нашел интересную реализацию хеширование с использованием класса sha1. Все что нужно для шифрования и дешифрования, так это вот этот метод.

```
    private string EncryptPass(string password)
    {
        SHA1 sha = SHA1.Create();
        string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
        return hash.Length > 49 ? hash.Substring(0, 49) : hash;
    }
```

Кто-нибудь объяснит почему на выходе получается хеш не из 160 битов, а из 80 битов?

И почему в return именно число 49

Comment: А почему вы решили что там 80 бит?

Comment: с дешифрованием вы верно погорячились.

Comment: Число 49 взято из справочника Потолоцкого

Comment: @PavelMayorov А зачем действительно такое число. 160 бит в base64 займут порядка 27 байт

Comment: @Mike на всякий случай же. Ну, вроде как `if (true == false)` некоторые пишут...

Comment: @SultanovShamil какие ваши аргументы?

Comment: Потому что посчитал во сколько символов хешируется строка пароля их оказалось 20, соответственно 80 бит. На самом деле должно быть 40 символов и соответственно 160 бит, как в документации

Comment: Мне для теста нужен данный алгоритм, никакого реального применения

Comment: @SOFL В байте в современных компьютерах 8 бит. 20*8=160. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82 Думаю вы путаете сам байт и его шестнадцеричное представление, обычно используемое для его отображения.

Comment: вы забываете, что у вас на выходе base64. В нём каждая буква(кроме, мб, последней) - 6бит

Comment: Точно, спасибо за ответы. Перепутал